# How to set slice separator color in Core plot

Tags: ios, core-plot

By default separator is the thin white line, how can I configure it, make it wider and change the color, it's possible?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
    CPTMutableLineStyle *line=[CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
        line.lineColor=[CPTColor grayColor];
        line.lineWidth = 1.0;

    pieChart.borderLineStyle=line;
```